# ChangePasswordAsync returns errorMessage incorrect password

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to send `POST` request and change user password with it, but I get

> HTTP 409 and incorrect password error message

```
if (request.Password != null)
{
    var hashedPassword = new PasswordHasher<User>().HashPassword(user, request.Password);
    var changePasswordResult = await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(user, user.PasswordHash, hashedPassword);
    if (!changePasswordResult.Succeeded)
    {
        return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict, new ErrorResponse
        {
            ErrorMessage = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, changePasswordResult.Errors.Select(x => x.Description))
        });
    }
}
```

Or should I change password like this?

```
var hashedPassword = new PasswordHasher<User>().HashPassword(user, request.Password);   
user.PasswordHash = hashedPassword;
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I validate the password from request and if it's valid, I update it

```
if (request.Password != null)
            {
                var valid = await new PasswordValidator<User>().ValidateAsync(_userManager, user, request.Password);

                if (!valid.Succeeded)
                {
                    return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict, new ErrorResponse
                    {
                        ErrorMessage = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, valid.Errors.Select(x => x.Description))
                    });
                }

                var hashedPassword = new PasswordHasher<User>().HashPassword(user, request.Password);
                user.PasswordHash = hashedPassword;
            }
```

Comment: It's the answer